# Rails simplifies a post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

In online bootcamp project, I'm creating a reddit clone, and I'm at the stage where I'm developing support for accessing posts. Here's the method for displaying all of the posts in the index.

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all
end
```

Here is the code that creates a link for each post, directing the user to the body of the post:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post.id) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Now the text states that "Rails lets us simplify this one step further, by allowing us to skip the post_path method altogether," and the resulting code in a separate file ends up omitting the post.id:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
   <p><%= link_to post.title, post %></p>
<% end %>
```

How is that possible? Does Rails just assume the post in question has the same id in the each element? Does making this change negatively affect the readability of the code?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't assume that id is the same. Different object to each link_to, so different url/path for each link_to. This is just a simpler or to be precise a "pithier" way of using link_to, thats all. A bit of rails magic to help lazy developers.

`link_to post.title, post` is same as this
`link_to post.title, post_path(post)` or `link_to post.title, post_path(post.id)`.

Rails has a concept of Polymorphic Routes which it uses to discern what the path should be, just simply using the object "post" instead of saying "post_path(post)" is enough in a link_to.

To understand this more, look at the implementation of link_to, url_for and polymorphic routes in Rails.